# why is the adjective 早い twice here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

A lot of things happen one after another, so the character says:

> 待て　待て待て　早い早い　展開が早い

Translated to "wait... wait, wait. Sh*t is moving way too fast!"

Does repeating ad mean "too much", or what?

Comment: I’m wondering why you are not asking why 待て is repeated twice and only asking about 早い…

Comment: in English too people say "wait" multiple times but not "fast'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, repeating an adjective only emphasizes the meaning. It does not automatically add the meaning of "overly". 長い長い is simply "long, long" or "very long", but not "too long".

Here, saying 早い just once corresponds to saying "(That's) too fast" in English. We don't need to say something long like 早すぎる in a situation like this. So 早い早い is simply 早い said twice for emphasis ("Too fast, too fast!"). It's not different from saying "wait, wait!"